# Form bigger than it supposed to be

Tags: c#, .net, forms, visual-studio

I'm just trying to create a very small form with an "X" button.

when I execute the whole thing, it's bigger than it supposed to be:
On the visual studio design editor:

[image]

But when running, this shows up:

[image]

The designer code:

```
        private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.button1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.button1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.button1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 7);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 26);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "X";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // Form3
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 40);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Name = "Form3";
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual;
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with forms but `AutoScaleDimensions` and `AutoScaleMode` seem like they could reset the form depending on the parameters?

Comment: Tried to comment these out, still occurs (these were auto-generated by VS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the below designer code as you were missing to set some of the properties for the button as well as the form.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // button1
    // 
    this.button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    this.button1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
    this.button1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12F, 
    System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, 
    ((byte)(0)));
    this.button1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
    this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.button1.Name = "button1";
    this.button1.AutoSize = true;  //you were missing this for the button
    this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 26);
    this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.button1.Text = "X";
    this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
    this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
    // 
    // Form1
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.AutoSize = true;  //you were missing this for the form
    this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;//also this 
    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 40);
    this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
    this.Name = "Form1";
    this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual;
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

Please check the designer code above and it works.

Comment: Thank you! seems to work. I just don't get why the auto generated code didn't work, but anyway much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to set the `Size.Width` and `Size.Height` of the form manually to whatever you want it to be.

Hope it helps!